# Display Week if Cell Date is between Certain Dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to assign a week # by month (Apr Week 1, Apr Week 2, etc.) to cells based on the date entered from a Google Form. I am trying to say 'If A2 date is Between C2 and D2 dates, then display "Apr Week 1" B2. If A2 date is Between C3 and D3 dates, then display "Apr Week 2", etc. I've tried with IF AND statements and even combining those with INDEX, but I keep getting errors. I need a formula that will work for any date during the year. Here is the link to the test sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5VuAON4WlBCbR2IilcaxJ8YgbKrw0R46upOJlR8pOQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {{43556, "Week 1"};
                                     {43562, "Week 2"};
                                     {43569, "Week 3"}}, 2)), )
```

[image: 0]

**more alternative solutions: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Comment: I need this formula for random dates for the entire year that are submitted from a form. I guess instead of week 1, week 2, week 3...maybe each entry should be Apr Week 1, Apr Week 2, May Week 1, May Week 2. But I obviously won't know the date until the form is submitted

Comment: I see, then your question is kinda misleading a lot

Comment: when your week starts? Monday?

Comment: My apologies. My first post and I didn't see the edit button until now. I have updated the question to better reflect the issue. The week starts on Sunday. Not sure if it makes things more difficult, but incomplete weeks need to go to their respective month.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), TEXT(A2:A, "mmm")&" Week "&
 WEEKNUM(A2:A, 2)-WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(A2:A, -1)+1, 2)+1, ))
```

[image: 0]